# Avoid third activity go back to first activity

Tags: java, android

I have three activities **A,B & C.**

**A** is Started screen / **B** is Login screen / **C** is Main tab bar screen

On A, I can push to B

On B, I can push to C and go back to A

On C, I want to avoid it go back to A, but can push to A (Means logout)

```
A <---> B ---> C ---> A
```

How I can achieve that?

**A.activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(StartedActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
StartedActivity.this.startActivity(i);
//finish(); //if i put finish() B cannot go back to A
```

**B.activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
finish();
```

**C.activity**

```
//This code is for logout, push to A.activity
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartedActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
finish();
```

So now the problem is I can press go back to A. How can i avoid it?

Comment: i dont understand the requirement here what did you meant by this `, I want to avoid it go back to A, but can push to A (Means logout)`

Comment: On C (Main tab bar screen), that means user login successfully, so I want to disable the go back button to A. but I have a logout button to push to A.

Comment: You can Override onBackPressed on activity C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(StartedActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
StartedActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

B.activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

C.activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartedActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

and override method `onBackPressed` on B.activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartedActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

so now you can apply flow A <---> B ---> C ---> A

one issue here is A will be reset when back from B

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in Activity A, and call `finish()` when you logged in.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("your-action-string".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

Register it in your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter("your-action-string")); // define your own action
}
```

Unregister it in `onDestroy`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: How to register?

Comment: Use a `LocalBroadcastManager`, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go back to the Activity A from Activity C then you set into manifests file.

```
       <activity
        android:name=".C"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:parentActivityName=".A"/>
```